# Jquery Selector contains AND ends with?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, datagrid

I have a page with a bunch of server generated controls (aspx, if it's important) in a `datagrid` with `TemplateColumns`. I want to add `$("").click()` functionality to every label in a `datagrid` that jquery `toggles` an `AssociatedID` control.

The names of each of these labels are long but predictable and are based on the parent grid and the id given to them... I've given that label an `ID` of `xmlReveal` and the `AssociatedIDControl` of `MainGridXMLTemplateLabel` and the parent grid is called `MainGrid` so that the rendered html for the label is something like

```
<label id="ctl00_plcMain_MainGrid_ctl08_xmlReveal" for="ctl00_plcMain_MainGrid_ctl08_MainGridXMLTemplateLabel">Click to reveal XML</label>
```

And then in a script tag, I have something like

```
$("XXXXXX").click(function(){
    $("#" + $(this).attr("for")).toggle()
});
```

*So what I need is the selector for `XXXXXX` where the `id` contains (`*=`) "`MainGrid`" and ends with (`$=`) `xmlReveal`*

*Edit: confused begins with (`^=`)and ends with (`$=`)... [fixed]*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use jQuery [ends with](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/)*($=)* like

```
$('[id*="MainGrid"][id$="xmlReveal"]')
```

When you combine selectors without a space, it will make the condition *contains* **AND** *ends with*

```js
console.log($('[id*="MainGrid"][id$="xmlReveal"]').length);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label id="ctl00_plcMain_MainGrid_ctl08_xmlReveal" for="ctl00_plcMain_MainGrid_ctl08_MainGridXMLTemplateLabel">Click to reveal XML</label>
```

Comment: Bang on, this is exactly what I needed. Did not know you could chain selector clauses like that. Thanks.